# Map data not filling entire map element until panned or moved

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-core, devextreme

I'm displaying a Google map in a DevExtreme Popup (uses Bootstrap). The map is returned as content of an ASP.NET Core View Component.

The map takes up the entire div (Google logo, controls, etc.) but the actual map data itself doesn't. It takes up a smaller area and just has gray elsewhere:

[image]

Now, as soon as I do anything with the map - pan it slightly, zoom in, zoom out, the map takes up the entire element:

[image]

Here is the ViewComponent content that creates the map:

```
<script>
var propertyMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 40.71, lng: -74.01 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});
</script>

<div id="mapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

And the AJAX function that retrieves the ViewComponent and places the content in the popup:

```
var mapPopup = $("<div />").appendTo($("body")).dxPopup({
width: 930,
height: 650,
visible: false,
closeOnOutsideClick: true
});

function showMapPopup() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Maps/PropertyMap",
}).done(function (data) {
    mapPopup.dxPopup({
        contentTemplate: data
    });
    mapPopup.dxPopup("instance").show();
    google.maps.event.trigger(propertyMap, 'resize');
});
}
```

I tried adding the `google.maps.event.trigger(propertyMap, 'resize')` event after showing the popup based on an older, similar question but it didn't help.

Comment: what sets the size of the `mapContainer` div?  Have you tried triggering the `resize` event on the map after that div is displayed (the popup is opened)?

Comment: `mapContainer` is 100% of parent, code didn't come through in the original post. Edited. And yes the resize event is triggered after showing the popup.

Comment: ^^ I don't think it is. See my answer.

Comment: What sets the size of the parent of the `mapContainer` div?

Comment: @geocodezip it get placed inside the `mapPopup` which has a predefined size of 930x650.

Comment: I don't see that in question, am I missing it?

Comment: Second code block `var mapPopup = $("<div />").appendTo($("body")).dxPopup({….`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the map creation in a function:

```
<script>
function createMap() {
    var propertyMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 40.71, lng: -74.01 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
}
</script>

<div id="mapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

And then not calling it until the modal is shown:

```
var mapPopup = $("<div />").appendTo($("body")).dxPopup({
    width: 930,
    height: 650,
    visible: false,
    closeOnOutsideClick: true,
    onShown: function() {
        createMap();
    }
});
```

There's a slight delay when the modal opens and the map showing since its not being created until then, but at least it fills the entire element now.

Comment: So you take 75% of my answer to write yours, post a worse solution (you said yourself there is a delay, which you don't have if you use the solution I took the time to write) and you don't even care up-voting or saying thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the map resize on the `shown` event of the popup.

See [Events](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/Popup/Show_and_Hide_the_Popup/#Events) and [Shown](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxPopup/Events/#shown).

Something like:

```
var popupOptions = {

    // [...] Other options here

    onShown: function() {

      google.maps.event.trigger(propertyMap, 'resize');
    }
};
```

And use these options when you create your popup instance.

According to the code you posted, I would suppose this should work:

```
var mapPopup = $("<div />").appendTo($("body")).dxPopup({
  width: 930,
  height: 650,
  visible: false,
  closeOnOutsideClick: true,
  onShown: function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(propertyMap, 'resize');
  }
});
```

Comment: Same behavior as before.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Can you access the `propertyMap` variable from there? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if this didn't help.

Comment: No console errors, `propertyMap` returns the Google Map object when called from the console.

Comment: Then please provide a MCVE as requested, as a code snippet in your question or an external fiddle.